# How to improve git diff output when commenting sections of code

Tags: git

I quite often find myself making a small change to a file that takes a long time time to run. The workflow is something like this:

```
<small edit to foo>
git add foo
<comment out huge swathe of foo which doesn't need testing>
<test change>
git restore foo
```

Works well. The only thing is, I like to check before `git restore`-ing that the commenting is the only change that will be lost. And it's here that I feel let down by git, and most of the other many diff tools I've configured git with.

I would expect that viewing a diff between a block of code in the index like this:

```
#
# JIRA-001: Do a thing
#

foo <<-EOF
    foo1
EOF

#
# JIRA-002: Do another thing
#

foo <<-EOF
    foo2
EOF
```

and a working copy that looks like this:

```
##
## JIRA-001: Do a thing
##
#
#foo <<-EOF
#    foo1
#EOF
#
##
## JIRA-002: Do another thing
##
#
#foo <<-EOF
#    foo2
#EOF
```

would make it trivial to see that the difference is simply that a hash has been prepended to a range of lines. But it's often not straightforward to tell, as the diff is presented in multiple hunks of removed and added lines, sometimes interleaved in such a way as to leave me unclear if an additional change has found it's way in.

In addition to running `git diff` I have also tried `git diff --word-diff-regex=. with somewhat better, but still to my mind not ideal, results. I have also tried all the different values for --diff-algorithm which makes no difference.

Can anyone suggest a way of viewing these diffs that will circumvent this issue?

Attaching partial outputs of `git diff` and `git diff --word-diff-regex=.` for comparison.

[image]

[image]

Comment: do you have ways to test your edited chunks in isolation that wouldn't require modifying all lines in the file ?

Comment: if your plan is to restore anyway, you could always delete lines rather than comment them

Comment: You could find a GUI that presents this in a better way and set it up as your `git difftool`.  e.g. I haven't used it, but supposedly [Meld](https://meldmerge.org/) is pretty good.

Comment: I'm surprised word-diff-regex=. chokes so hard on this sample, at a guess it's getting fooled by the spurious whole-line matches the insertion introduced so the word-diff processing isn't even seeing the right hunks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid the rampant punning, use a more distinguishable marker and tell the word diff about it:

```
$ git diff --word-diff-regex='#.|.' test test2
diff --git a/test b/test2
index 11c83b7..d92fc45 100644
--- a/test
+++ b/test2
@@ -1,15 +1,15 @@
{+#x+}#
{+#x+}# JIRA-001: Do a thing
{+#x+}#
{+#x+}
{+#x+}foo <<-EOF
{+#x+}    foo1
{+#x+}EOF
{+#x+}
{+#x+}#
{+#x+}# JIRA-002: Do another thing
{+#x+}#
{+#x+}
{+#x+}foo <<-EOF
{+#x+}    foo2
{+#x+}EOF
```

Comment: I'm liking that, even though I would expect word-diff-regex=. to handle this. But 'rampant punning'?

Comment: The `#`'s you added to comment out the whole thing are indistinguishable from the `#`s that were already part of the code, they mean different things in context but they're easy to mistake for each other. They're puns. Pretty sure what's happening is the word-diff processing is only operating on identified hunks, and the punned `#` lines are causing the hunk boundaries to come untracked.

Comment: This makes perfect sense. Presumably the word diff still starts with a line diff before doing word diffs block by block, so then it wouldn't even see those punned `#` lines at all.

Comment: @joanis: yes, `git diff --word-diff` starts with a line oriented diff, then edits that for presentation. This sometimes results in weirdness, when the word diff winds up being empty for instance.